# I create a button event in storyboard, but I get an error

Tags: c#, xamarin, uibutton

Error:

> Type 'UserProfileViewController' already defines a member called 'LogOutButtonClicked'

Why am I getting this error if I am creating the event in the "Properties" section of the button, placing it in the correct class, and there is no other function with a remotely similar name?

How do I correct this?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Show us your code buddy. It would make it easier to debug it or reproduce the error.

Comment: Where is code? What to correct?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin creates partial classes to map from your XIB/Storyboards to your code.

So I think your Method "LogOutButtonClicked" is already implemented within this partial class.

For example search for "LogOutButtonClicked" within you Project. And I will think you will find your duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Your storyboard for `UserProfileViewController` is linked with a cs file of the same name `UserProfileViewController.cs`

This error is happening because of duplication, Check your `UserProfileViewController.cs` file and see if there is a property a field or a method with the same name as the event that you have created. The reason could be you have two event methods with the name `LogOutButtonClicked`